# How to add views dynamically to a RelativeLayout already declared in the xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I declared a `RelativeLayout` in a xml layout file. Now I want to add `Views` from code to the existing Layout. I added a `Button` dynamically to this existing layout as below through code:

```
rLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout); 
        LayoutParams lprams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button tv1 = new Button(this); 
        tv1.setText("Hello"); 
        tv1.setLayoutParams(lprams); 
        tv1.setId(1); 
        rLayout.addView(tv1);
```

Now I need to add another `Button` to the right of the already added `Button`.  I am not able to find the way in which I can add the new one to the  right of the previously added button.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the rule `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF` for the second added `Button` `LayoutParams`:

```
    // first Button
    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button tv1 = new Button(this);
    tv1.setText("Hello");
    tv1.setLayoutParams(lprams);
    tv1.setId(1);
    rLayout.addView(tv1);

    // second Button
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button tv2 = new Button(this);
    tv1.setText("Hello2");
    newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(newParams);
    tv2.setId(2);
    rLayout.addView(tv2);
```

Comment: what happen if I have many dynamic button and  the penultimate touches the edge? What happen with the last??

Comment: @zhelon it will probably be pushed outside or squeezed. If you know you will have many buttons than you need to wrap the `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView` or `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: If I use RelativeLayout as I dynamically create buttons, how do I know at what time he touched the edge?

Comment: @zhelon It would be complicated to do this with layouts like `Relativelayout`, you probably want to implement a custom view if this is important for you.

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help you, try it.

```
rLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
LayoutParams lprams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TableLayout tl=new TableLayout(this);
rLayout.addView(tl); 

TableRow tr1=new TableRow(this);
tl.addView(tr1);

Button btn1 = new Button(this);
btn1.setText("Hello");
btn1.setLayoutParams(lprams);
btn1.setId(1);
tr1.addView(btn1);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this); 
tv1.setWidth(40);
tv1.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tr1.addView(tv1);


Button btn2 = new Button(this);
btn2.setText("World");
btn2.setLayoutParams(lprams);
btn2.setId(2);
tr1.addView(btn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another button:

```
Button tv2 = new Button(this);
tv2.setText("World");
tv2.setLayoutParams(lprams);
tv2.setId(2);
```

Add add it into your RelativeLayout:

```
rLayout.addView(tv2);
```