# Android: Add textViews in RelativeLayout Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have an RelativeLayout and I would like to insert some textViews.

Here is the code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/JournalSearchListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/JournalsSearchTextView"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/JournalSearchProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And how I am doing this programmatically:

```
RelativeLayout journals = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.JournalSearchListView);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
for (int i=0;i< authorNames.size();i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(i); 
    tv.setText(authorNames.get(i));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Integer a = tv.hashCode();
    map.put(a,authorNames.get(i));
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
    journals.addView(tv, params1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             System.out.println("Clicked "+ map.get(v.hashCode()) );    
         }
    });   
}
```

But the problem is that each textView is in the same position as the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());`

You are setting it to be below itself?
If you want them below eachother do it this way:

```
RelativeLayout journals = (RelativeLayout);
findViewById(R.id.JournalSearchListView);
LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(context);
lL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for (int i=0;i< authorNames.size();i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(i); 
    tv.setText(authorNames.get(i));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Integer a = tv.hashCode();
    map.put(a,authorNames.get(i));

    if(i!=0){
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i-1);
    }

    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Clicked "+ map.get(v.hashCode()) ); 
        }
    });

    lL.addView(tv);   

}

journals.addview(lL);
```

Comment: Okay, why do you even want to use relativelayout?
If all you want to do is to place items below eachother, use a linearlayout. And my name is Anders, not Andreas :-)

Comment: Oh sorry Anders, my mistake. I would like to use a relative layout because I have an progressBar in my layout, which is positioned in the middle of the layout, which is not possible with the linear layout, right?

Comment: Then in the relative layout add a linearlayout :)

Comment: Great answer Anders, i dit like this and this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
journals.addView(tv, params1);
```

This basically says *"place the textview below itself"*. Which of course doesn't work, so all the views will take the default position within the RelativeLayout. Use the id of the TextView you added before instead *(or the id of the progress bar if you insert the first element)*.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but I am trying the Andreas's method without success.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Every UI object must have a layout parameter
        int widthContent = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int heightContent = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        // Create relative layout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParamsName = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthContent,heightContent);
        rlParamsName.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);   

        // Create a linear layout to add new object as vertical
        LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(context);
        lL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i=0;i< 3;i++) {

            // Every time create new object of text view 
            TextView objDonateTextView = new TextView(this);
            objDonateTextView.setLayoutParams(rlParamsName);
            objDonateTextView.setText("Donate");
            objDonateTextView.setId(i);
            objDonateTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            objDonateTextView.setTextColor(0xFF000000);

            lL.addView(objDonateTextView);

        }

        //Add button number two to the activity.
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.row_special);   
        rl.addView(lL);
```

//vKj

Answer (score 0):

can use addRule function for same

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawerContent);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );


    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i);
         btn.setText("some_text");

         lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, <Id>);

         layout.addView(tv2, lp); 
    }
```

Comment: basicaly uncomment the line lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, <Id>); and provide the <id> because as you know in  RelativeLayout one aligns his view in relative to other view so you need to give other view id....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814718/android-add-textviews-in-relativelayout-programatically/10814759#10814759

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666019/how-to-add-views-dynamically-to-a-relativelayout-already-declared-in-the-xml-lay

Comment: Thank you but this is still not resolving my problem, i am creating textViews dynamicaly and owervriting their names...