# How to align these 2 buttons next to each other programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I have written this piece of code. But it is not giving the proper result. Please let me know where is the mistake. And I don't want to use Linear Layout.

Here is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_relativeLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

String[] but = {"Hello", "Bye"};
int buttonCount = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  customLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_relativeLayout1);
```

//customLayout is object of relativelayout.

```
    buttonCount = but.length;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button [] butArray = new Button[buttonCount];


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {

        butArray[i] = new Button(this);
        butArray[i].setLayoutParams(params);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Btnparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) butArray[i].getLayoutParams();
        butArray[i].setText(but[i]);
        butArray[i].setId(i+1); // Setting the ids

        butArray[i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0);
        butArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if (butArray[i].getId() != 1)
        {
            Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, butArray[i-1].getId());
            butArray[i].setLayoutParams(Btnparams);
            customLayout.addView(butArray[i]);
        }
        else
        {   
            butArray[i].setLayoutParams(Btnparams);
            customLayout.addView(butArray[i]);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you tried this **Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, butArray[i].getId());**?

Comment: Why don't you want to use LinearLayout? It's perfect for displaying 2 buttons next to eachother.. Just add 2 buttons in the LL with the orientation of de LL set to horizontal. Add weight=1 to the buttons to let them be the same size (50% of screen).

Comment: @PieterAelse the number of buttons will increase. If I have to display 6 buttons, like 3 on top and 3 below the other three then how to do is using Linearlayout?

Comment: @CapDroid Yes, I have tried it but still the same result.

Comment: @user3522370 If you know when you want to begin a new row, LinearLayout is still very usefull to use. Let me craft something together and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OFhoryzontally or vertically align?
so for vertically

```
Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, butArray[i-1].getId());
customLayout.addView(butArray[i], Btnparams);
```

or for horizontally

```
Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, butArray[i-1].getId());
customLayout.addView(butArray[i], Btnparams);
```

instead of

```
Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, butArray[i-1].getId());
            butArray[i].setLayoutParams(Btnparams);
            customLayout.addView(butArray[i]);
```

Comment: may I know what is tv in tv.getId()?

Comment: No, it is not. I tried for horizontal. Is it possible for you to paste your code here?

Comment: @user3522370 each butArray[i] has id?
do you correct else block in your code?

Comment: What changes I should make to else block? And Yes, butArray[i] has ids. I'm setting the id like butArray[i].setId(i+1).

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout is very nice to use if you want do dynamically add Views and scale them the same. For example if you want to add buttons and have max 3 buttons per row, you can also use another LinearLayout to make a new row.

I 'abuse' the LinearLayout row and a Button for layoutparams templating.

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/ll_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_row1"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Example code:

```
// Get LL and template params
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_root);
LinearLayout row1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_row1);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams llRowParams = row1.getLayoutParams();
ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParams = findViewById(R.id.btn1).getLayoutParams();

// Make new button
Button newBtn = new Button(context);
newBtn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
newBtn.setText("Button 3");

// Add button to row1
row1.addView(newBtn);

// Add new row
LinearLayout row2 = new LinearLayout(context);
row2.setLayoutParams(llRowParams);
root.addView(row2);

// TODO: add buttons to new row
// TODO: some logic to decide between adding to row or creating new row and adding button
```

Note: code is not tested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Is it possible to create 9(just an example) buttons in 3X3 grid format programmatically?

Comment: Sure, you can build some logic to run for 9 times and add buttons. But that's not difficult, try on your own :).

Answer (score 0):

```
 buttonCount = but.length;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button [] butArray = new Button[buttonCount];


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {

        butArray[i] = new Button(this);
        butArray[i].setLayoutParams(params);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Btnparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) butArray[i].getLayoutParams();
        butArray[i].setText(but[i]);
        butArray[i].setId(i+1); // Setting the ids

        butArray[i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0);
        butArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if (i != 0) {  
            Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i-1);
        }
        customLayout.addView(butArray[i], Btnparams);



    }
```

Comment: Still the same. I don't know why they are overlapping when I use your above modified code. :(

Comment: @user3522370 maybe we will include LinearLayout in RelativeLayout?

Comment: @user3522370 [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814718/android-add-textviews-in-relativelayout-programatically)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will use linear layout for now.

Comment: @user3522370 so some LinearLayout in vertical or horizontal orienation is RelativeLayout)