# TextColor and other change on dynamically add view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox, colorfilter

i have an activity and dynamically add some views on it. the textcolor and colorfilter of the dynamic edittexts are different and i'm confused why ?
and my checkbox has the same issue too.
any one can help ?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/txtSearchSpecialAttrTitle"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SearchSpecialAttrEditText"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is the way i add this to my activity.

```
LinearLayout llSpecialAttribsContainer = (LinearLayout) activityWeakReference.get().findViewById(R.id.llSearchSpecialAttributesContainer);
CardView cardView = (CardView) Global.inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_int_field_schema, llSpecialAttribsContainer, false);
                                TextView txtTitle = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.txtSearchSpecialAttrTitle);
                                txtTitle.setText(specialAttrib.persianFieldName);

                                EditText editText = (EditText) cardView.findViewById(R.id.SearchSpecialAttrEditText);
                                editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Global.appContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.appBarColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                                editText.setTag(specialAttrib.fieldName);

                                llSpecialAttribsContainer.addView(cardView);
```

any help ???

Full XML Added

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="فیلتر جستجو" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/activitySearch_Spinner_Parent"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <requestFocus/>
        </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/activitySearch_Spinner_Child"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/activitySearch_Spinner_GrandChild"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSearchMaxPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=" تا " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSearchMinPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center">
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="قیمت از "
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/llSearchSpecialAttributesContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmitSearch"
                style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".6"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="اعمال فیلتر"
                android:textColor="@color/appBarColor"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCancelSearch"
                style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:text="لغو"
                android:textColor="@color/appBarColor"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post full xml file please

Comment: full xml posted @SaurabhBhandari

Comment: U need to provide id to your Linear Layout in which you want add dynamically editText. And get reference in your class. for more ifo follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666019/how-to-add-views-dynamically-to-a-relativelayout-already-declared-in-the-xml-lay

Comment: i alerady set id as "llSearchSpecialAttributesContainer" for linearlayout. the inflated views add successfully but the problem is that textcolor of added Edittexts are different from others@SaurabhBhandari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to get the activity inflator , but i get inflator from application context and that cause the dynamic views not have the application theme !

Best Regards