# RelativeLayout with tags instead ids

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to create some Views in .xml programmatically, so I want to put tags in the View, since I can't put a String as id (at least I think so) inside the Java code.
I have a .xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View  <!--I change its color in the Java code-->
        android:tag="color0" 
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/view1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view1"
        android:tag="text1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="U$ 32,44"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/money1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="03/03/2018"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/money1"
        android:id="@+id/data1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to say `android:layout_toRightOf="color0"`, since **color0** is a tag? 
Should I stop using `RelativeLayout` and start trying the `LinearLayout` for this specific situation?

**Expected Result:**
[image]

Comment: Don't use RelativeLayouts in situations like this. You should be using a horizontal linear layout

Comment: _create some Views in .xml programmatically_ - what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that i will make more lines like this but dynamically in the Java code

Comment: You can do that by inflating the given layout however many times you need. Beyond that, it's unclear why you can't just use the ID there. Why are you trying to use the tag instead?

Comment: Ids don't have to be unique in the view hierarchy, as long as you don't need to save their state you can just use ids there, even if you're inflating many of those xmls

Comment: @MikeM. I'm trying to use the tag because if I set the id in the Java code, I can only use numbers. I wanted to set an id like "money0, money1, money2", then I'm going with the tags. I think I'll leave the `RelativeLayout` and use the `LinearLayout`, it seems easier

Comment: If you just inflate that layout as needed, you won't have to set the ID.

Answer (score -1):

`android:layout_toRightOf` it accept only id.
You can assign numeric ids to views in java code.
`View view=new View(this);view.setId(2333);`

Comment: What does that have to do with the question asked?

Answer (score -1):

First of all it will be a lot easier if you use a **`LinearLayout`** instead of a **`RelativeLayout`** in your scenario.

Secondly, if you want to add views at runtime inside a **`RelativeLayout`** then you might wanna see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666019/how-to-add-views-dynamically-to-a-relativelayout-already-declared-in-the-xml-lay).

Comment: Yeah... I think I'm going to do it with `LinearLayout`... I was trying de `RelativeLayout` because I could use the `alignParentEnd` for the money TextView, but I'll try the Linear to solve the "id / tags problem". Thank you